# How do I access the service response data if I am returning an array of custom map with promise as an object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Here is my code:

```
function myobject(name, anotherArray){
 this.name = name; this.anotherArray = anotherArray;
}

//$scope.myObjects is an array of myObject


function pMap(name, promise){
    this.name= name;
    this.promise = promise;
};

var getAllPromises = function(){
    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.myobjects, function(myobject) {
        urlPath = <someurl>+myobject.name;
        var promise = $http({
            url   : urlPath,
            method: 'GET'
        });
        promises.push(new pMap(myobject.name, promise));
    });
    return $q.all(promises);
};
```

Now when I accept each promise as follows in a separate function using .then, I am not sure how to access the json returned by the service above?

```
 getAllPromises.then(function(pData){
                    angular.forEach(pData, function(pMap){
                        var name = pMap.name;
                        var responseArray = promiseMap.<?> --> how do I access the json returned by the service here?
<I need to assign $scope.myobjects.anotherArray to data returned by the promise but this has to be done using the name attribute of each myobject>

                    });
                });
```

Any ideas how to do this? 
New to promise pattern and angularjs in general

Comment: Where are you assigning `j` ? As far as I can see you're just making a whole lot of `pMap` objects where `j` is `undefined`

Comment: Why not just return the `promises` array instead of a new promise?

Comment: I don't understand why you're putting a map of promises in the array. You can just access the resolved promises by their index, they will have the same index as they had when you `push`ed them in

Comment: What is `myobjects` here? Could we see the code for that? It looks like its an array judging by its name, but then you want to assign the resolved promises to a `anotherArray` property of `myobject`?

Comment: Added myObject. And yes you are right.

Comment: Please use a proper IIFE instead of `new function() {…}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
var promises;
angular.forEach($scope.myobjects, function(myobject) {
    var promise = $http({
        url   : urlPath,
        method: 'GET'
    });
    promises.push(promise);
});
$q.all(promises).then(function(resolvedPromises) {
  var firstPushedPromise = resolvedPromises[0];
  //var xPushedPromise = resolvedPromises[x];
}
```

`resolvedPromises` is an array here, the index will be the same as you pushed them in. You can just access every other promise by their index.

I'm not sure why you're looping over `$scope.myobjects` if you're not going to use `myobject` though.

Comment: I just added more context so that the problem can be clear. Please re-read the description

Comment: For now, I have solved this issue by just making the service returning a name as well in the json itself so that I do not have to worry about mapping $scope.myObjects.name with each promise. But this is a standing question if someone wants to do this.

Comment: Also, to your answer - Lets say the urlPath returns a bunch of jsons. So does promise[0] return the array of jsons itself? Or does it have to be like promise[0].<something>? I am printing promise[0] and I only see [object object] in the console even though the json list is huge.

Comment: Yes it returns the resolved promises in order no matter if they're arrays or not. You can always use console.log("my obj", obj), console.dir(obj) or just plain debugging to get a better look on the returned data